# Python doesn't take my input but there is no error (code continues running)

Tags: python, input, tic-tac-toe

I continue learning the basics of Python by extending my TicTacToe game. It now lets the player choose difficulty. It seems that it works (finally), but sometimes I experience a strange issue.

Note that I use Google Colab (in case that is relevant).

This is a turn-based game, meaning I play my turn, then computer plays, then me etc until someone wins or we get to a tie (the order depends on what you input in the beginning, sometimes computer plays first). But sometimes, when I'm asked for my input and I give it, the input line disappears but nothing happens. My input is not shown on the board, the input line disappears, and the computer doesn't play because it's waiting for me to finish my turn. The code continues running (and Google Colab marks the code is currently at human_move(), meaning it's waiting for my input). It doesn't give an error message on its own, but see below for what's shown when I interrupt it manually.

I don't really know how to recreate the issue, other than playing many times in Colab (ony my own computer, the issue repeats almost always). So far it's happened on medium and hard difficulty. Here's how the last board looked when it got stuck (I played Os, computer played Xs). For my next move I pressed 4, then the input line disappeared without playing my move:

```
+-------+-------+-------+ 
|       |       |       | 
|   O   |   2   |   3   | 
|       |       |       | 
+-------+-------+-------+ 
|       |       |       | 
|   4   |   X   |   X   | 
|       |       |       | 
+-------+-------+-------+ 
|       |       |       | 
|   7   |   8   |   O   | 
|       |       |       | 
+-------+-------+-------+
```

I'm attaching my full code. I know it's long and I'm sorry, but look below for an error message to maybe make it more clear.

```
# I need these functions to make everything work
from IPython.core.display import clear_output
from random import randrange

# Sets the board at the beginning
official_board = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

# Just displays the current board
def display_board(board):
  print(
      "\n+-------+-------+-------+",
      "\n|       |       |       |",
      "\n|  ",board[0],"  |  ",board[1],"  |  ",board[2],"  |",
      "\n|       |       |       |",
      "\n+-------+-------+-------+",
      "\n|       |       |       |",
      "\n|  ",board[3],"  |  ",board[4],"  |  ",board[5],"  |",
      "\n|       |       |       |",
      "\n+-------+-------+-------+",
      "\n|       |       |       |",
      "\n|  ",board[6],"  |  ",board[7],"  |  ",board[8],"  |",
      "\n|       |       |       |",
      "\n+-------+-------+-------+"
      )

# Asks player to define who plays first (human or computer). Impacts the order of turns.
def who_plays_first():
  global first_player
  while True:
    first_player = int(input("Choose who plays first: 1 for human, 2 for computer"))
    if first_player == 1 or first_player == 2:
      break
    print("invalid input, read the instruction")
  if first_player == 1:
    first_player = "human"
  else:
    first_player = "computer"
  return(first_player)

# Asks player to set difficulty. Impacts how computer decides on its move.
def choose_difficulty():
  global difficulty
  while True:
    difficulty = int(input("Choose difficulty: 1 = easy, 2 = medium, 3 = hard"))
    if difficulty == 1 or difficulty == 2 or difficulty == 3:
      break
    print("invalid input, read the instruction")
  if difficulty == 1:
    difficulty = "easy"
  elif difficulty == 2:
    difficulty = "medium"
  else:
    difficulty = "hard"
  return(difficulty)

# Makes a list of free fields. Used in other functions.
def make_list_of_free_fields(board):
  list_of_free_fields = []
  for field in range(1,10):
    if field in board:
      list_of_free_fields.append(field)
  return(list_of_free_fields)

# Checks whether the player (defined by the sign) won.
def victory_for(sign, board):
  if (board[0] == sign and board[1] == sign and board[2] == sign or 
      board[3] == sign and board[4] == sign and board[5] == sign or 
      board[6] == sign and board[7] == sign and board[8] == sign or 
      board[0] == sign and board[3] == sign and board[6] == sign or 
      board[1] == sign and board[4] == sign and board[7] == sign or 
      board[2] == sign and board[5] == sign and board[8] == sign or 
      board[0] == sign and board[4] == sign and board[8] == sign or 
      board[2] == sign and board[4] == sign and board[6] == sign):
    return True
  else:
    return False

# Asks the human player to make their move.
def human_move():
  while True:
    human_input = int(input("Choose a field"))
    if human_input in make_list_of_free_fields(official_board):
      break
    print("You must choose one of the free fields on the board by typing 1-9")
  official_board[human_input-1] = "O"

# This is how the computer makes its move.
# Depends on the difficulty.
def computer_move():
  
  # This is how the computer plays on easy
  if difficulty == "easy":
    
    # Computer plays a random move out of the list of available fields
    while True:
      computer_input = randrange(10)
      if computer_input in make_list_of_free_fields(official_board):
        break
    official_board[computer_input-1] = "X"
  
  # this is how the computer plays on medium 
  # (or hard if less than 2 turns available for computer)  
  elif difficulty == "medium" or len(make_list_of_free_fields(official_board)) < 3:
        
    # Check whether there's a (list of) move(s) that would guarantee computer victory
    # if yes, play a random move out of that list and end the function
    # if not, move to the next part of the function
    brings_computer_victory = []
    for field in make_list_of_free_fields(official_board):
      temp_board = official_board[:]
      temp_move = field
      temp_board[temp_move-1] = "X"
      if victory_for("X", temp_board) == True:
        brings_computer_victory.append(temp_move)
    if brings_computer_victory != []:
      while True:
        computer_input = randrange(10)
        if computer_input in brings_computer_victory:
          break
      official_board[computer_input-1] = "X"
      return
    
    # Check whether there's a (list of) move(s) that would guarantee human victory
    # Prevent human from winning by playing a random move out of that list and end function
    # if there is no such move, move to the next part of the function
    brings_human_victory = []
    for field in make_list_of_free_fields(official_board):
      temp_board = official_board[:]
      temp_move = field
      temp_board[temp_move-1] = "O"
      if victory_for("O", temp_board) == True:
        brings_human_victory.append(temp_move)
    if brings_human_victory != []:
      while True:
        computer_input = randrange(10)
        if computer_input in brings_human_victory:
          break
      official_board[computer_input-1] = "X"
      return
    
    # if you got to here, it means there were no moves that would
    # guarantee computer or human victory, so
    # play a random field as if you were playing on easy.
    while True:
      computer_input = randrange(10)
      if computer_input in make_list_of_free_fields(official_board):
        break
    official_board[computer_input-1] = "X"

  # this is how the computer plays on hard (assuming more than 2 turns available)
  # the first part is the same as on medium, i.e.
  # if it's possible to win, use to opportunity, if not
  # check whether human will be able to win and stop him.
  # if none of that is possible, don't play random (like on medium)
  # but be smart (see further code and comments for details)
  else:

    # Check whether there's a (list of) move(s) that would guarantee computer victory
    # if yes, play a random move out of that list and end the function
    # if not, move to the next part of the function
    brings_computer_victory = []
    for field in make_list_of_free_fields(official_board):
      temp_board = official_board[:]
      temp_move = field
      temp_board[temp_move-1] = "X"
      if victory_for("X", temp_board) == True:
        brings_computer_victory.append(temp_move)
    if brings_computer_victory != []:
      while True:
        computer_input = randrange(10)
        if computer_input in brings_computer_victory:
          break
      official_board[computer_input-1] = "X"
      return
    
    # Check whether there's a (list of) move(s) that would guarantee human victory
    # Prevent human from winning by playing a random move out of that list and end function
    # if there is no such move, move to the next part of the function
    brings_human_victory = []
    for field in make_list_of_free_fields(official_board):
      temp_board = official_board[:]
      temp_move = field
      temp_board[temp_move-1] = "O"
      if victory_for("O", temp_board) == True:
        brings_human_victory.append(temp_move)
    if brings_human_victory != []:
      while True:
        computer_input = randrange(10)
        if computer_input in brings_human_victory:
          break
      official_board[computer_input-1] = "X"
      return
    
    # if you got to here, it means there were no moves that would
    # guarantee computer or human victory, so we move to next step.
    # We'll look two moves in advance to see if playing something now
    # creates opportunities for later.
    
    # We start by checking opportunities for the computer.
    # We will have two new lists:
    #   a) one saying which moves give two winning options in the next turn.
    #   b) one saying which moves give one winning option in the next turn.
    # if the list of moves giving 2 options is not empty, we randomly pick a move from there.
    # else, if the list of moves with 1 option is not empty, we randomly draw from there.
    # if we did one of the two previous options, we end the function.

    
    # First, let's create the lists to determine which moves would give
    # computer one or two winning options in the turn after.

    gives_two_options = []
    gives_one_option = []
    for first_move in make_list_of_free_fields(official_board):
      board_after_first_move = official_board[:]
      board_after_first_move[first_move-1] = "X"
      opportunities = 0
      for second_move in make_list_of_free_fields(board_after_first_move):
        board_after_second_move = board_after_first_move[:]
        board_after_second_move[second_move-1] ="X"
        if victory_for("X", board_after_second_move) == True:
          opportunities += 1
      if opportunities > 1:
        gives_two_options.append(first_move)
      if opportunities == 1:
        gives_one_option.append(first_move)
    
    # if there's a list of moves which would give computer two winning options,
    # play a random move from that list and end function.
    # If not, check whether there's list of moves which would give one 
    # winning option (and play randomly from there) and end function.
    # If no such lists exist, go on with the code.

    if gives_two_options != []:
      while True:
        computer_input = randrange(10)
        if computer_input in gives_two_options:
          break
      official_board[computer_input-1] = "X"
      return
    
    if gives_one_option != []:
      while True:
        computer_input = randrange(10)
        if computer_input in gives_one_option:
          break
      official_board[computer_input-1] = "X"
      return
    
    # if we're here, it means there were no good opportunities for computer.
    # so let's check if there are any for the human, and then prevent them.
    # Let's create the lists to determine which moves would give
    # human one or two winning options in the turn after.

    gives_two_options = []
    gives_one_option = []
    for first_move in make_list_of_free_fields(official_board):
      board_after_first_move = official_board[:]
      board_after_first_move[first_move-1] = "O"
      opportunities = 0
      for second_move in make_list_of_free_fields(board_after_first_move):
        board_after_second_move = board_after_first_move[:]
        board_after_second_move[second_move-1] ="O"
        if victory_for("O", board_after_second_move) == True:
          opportunities += 1
      if opportunities > 1:
        gives_two_options.append(first_move)
      if opportunities == 1:
        gives_one_option.append(first_move)

    # if there's a list of moves which would give human two winning options,
    # play a random move from that list and end function.
    # If not, check whether there's list of moves which would give one 
    # winning option (and play randomly from there) and end function.
    # If no such lists exist, go on with the code.

    if gives_two_options != []:
      while True:
        computer_input = randrange(10)
        if computer_input in gives_two_options:
          break
      official_board[computer_input-1] = "X"
      return
    
    if gives_one_option != []:
      while True:
        computer_input = randrange(10)
        if computer_input in gives_one_option:
          break
      official_board[computer_input-1] = "X"
      return

    # if you got to here, it means there were no moves that would
    # create meaningful opportunities for computer or the human, so
    # play a random field as if you were playing on easy.
    while True:
      computer_input = randrange(10)
      if computer_input in make_list_of_free_fields(official_board):
        break
    official_board[computer_input-1] = "X"

# This is the final piece of code that connects all the functions.
who_plays_first()
choose_difficulty()
clear_output()

if first_player == "human":

  display_board(official_board)

  while True:
    human_move()
    clear_output()
    display_board(official_board)
    if victory_for("O", official_board) == True:
      print("You won!")
      break
    if len(make_list_of_free_fields(official_board)) == 0:
      print("it's a tie")
      break
    computer_move()
    clear_output()
    display_board(official_board)
    if victory_for("X", official_board) == True:
      print("You lost!")
      break

else:

  while True:
    computer_move()
    clear_output()
    display_board(official_board)
    if victory_for("X", official_board) == True:
      print("You lost!")
      break
    if len(make_list_of_free_fields(official_board)) == 0:
      print("it's a tie")
      break
    human_move()
    clear_output()
    display_board(official_board)
    if victory_for("O", official_board) == True:
      print("You won!")
      break
```

After further inspection and many tries to recreate the problem in Colab, I failed to reach anything. But then I decided to run the code on my own computer (Anaconda, Visual Studio Code, Jupiter, not sure if relevant). There, the problem occurs much more frequently (almost on every move I make). Python doesn't raise an error on its own, but the code seems to be stuck in a loop. When I stop it manually, I get this error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
c:\Users\Divo\Downloads\TicTacToe_2.ipynb Cell 10 in <cell line: 6>()
     37   print("it's a tie")
     38   break
---> 39 human_move()
     40 clear_output()
     41 display_board(official_board)

c:\Users\Divo\Downloads\TicTacToe_2.ipynb Cell 10 in human_move()
      2 def human_move():
      3   while True:
----> 4     human_input = int(input("Choose a field"))
      5     if human_input in make_list_of_free_fields(official_board):
      6       break

ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

Comment: There is just way too much code here

Comment: sorry roganjosh, I know it's long, but as I said, I don't know how to pinpoint the issue. I would guess it's something within the function human_move(), that one is not very long. That's the part where Colab remains stuck while waiting for my input which I cannot give.

Comment: I suggest you first spend time on finding out how to reproduce the issue. It is very unlikely that someone in the community is going to do this for you.

Comment: thanks, I'll keep trying to recreate it. Now I played like 30 games and no issues whatsoever. I'm close to marking it as an occasional Colab bug and calling this a finished code, lol.

Comment: I updated the post with something new I found out while running the code on my own computer.

Answer (score 0):

The error tells you what is wrong, you are trying to parse something that can't be interpreted as an integer, in this case an empty string `''`. It is generally very dangerous to parse human input as an integer, without first checking that it can actually be converted to an integer. First you could check if it is numeric, and then if it is in the desired range (and then that it is in a free spot, like you do):

```
if human_input.isnumeric():
    if human_input in range(1, 10):
```